# in li $v0, 8 what means 8? mips

Tags: assembly, mips

I know that's a stupid question for you, but in those lines:

```
la $a0, input
li $v0, 4 
syscall
```

---

```
la $a0, insert 
la $a1, insert 
li $v0, 8
syscall
```

What means 4 and 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`4` is a number meaning “four,” 8 is a number meaning “eight.”

The instruction `li $v0, 8` loads the register `v0` with the value `8`. Here, `8` is probably the number of the system call you want to invoke with the `syscall` instruction. What system call this number corresponds to depends on the operating system you run this code under. The same thing applies to `li $v0, 4` earlier on.

Answer (score 1):

`4` is the system call code for print_str.

`8` is the system call code for read_string.

Comment: How can you know the operating system? OP didn't provide any information in this regard.

Comment: One can not _know_ this with absolute certainty based on the information provided, but one can say that this is very likely. As someone who frequents this tag, I can say that the majority of questions asked here are from people who are using the SPIM simulator or one of its derivates (QtSpim, MARS), and the code in the question matches the system calls available in those simulators.